# ValueError: Unknown layer: CapsuleLayer

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

I have defined a custom layer named `CapsuleLayer`. The actual model has been defined in a separate class. I have loaded the weights into the actual model and have saved the model in an `.h5` file. However when I try to load the model using `load_model(filepath)` I get the error

> ValueError: Unknown layer: CapsuleLayer

How can I incorporate the custom layer into my model while loading the saved model.

Answer (score 28):

C.f. Keras FAQ, ["Handling custom layers (or other custom objects) in saved models"](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#handling-custom-layers-or-other-custom-objects-in-saved-models):

> If the model you want to load includes custom layers or other custom
>   classes or functions, you can pass them to the loading mechanism via
>   the custom_objects argument:
>
> ```
> from keras.models import load_model
> # Assuming your model includes instance of an "AttentionLayer" class
> model = load_model('my_model.h5', custom_objects={'AttentionLayer': AttentionLayer})
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use a custom object scope:
>
> ```
> from keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
>
> with CustomObjectScope({'AttentionLayer': AttentionLayer}):
>     model = load_model('my_model.h5')
> ```
>
> Custom objects handling works the same way for load_model,
>   model_from_json, model_from_yaml:
>
> ```
> from keras.models import model_from_json
> model = model_from_json(json_string, custom_objects={'AttentionLayer': AttentionLayer})
> ```

---

In your case, `model = load_model('my_model.h5', custom_objects={'CapsuleLayer': CapsuleLayer})` should solve your problem.

Comment: I need to import the class as well I guess.

Comment: Exact. The `custom_objects` parameter basically has for purpose to pass your custom class and its name to `load_model()`, so that it can recognize and recover it from the saved files.

Comment: I am getting an error. TypeError: __init__() takes atleast 3 arguments (1 given). What could be the problem.?

Comment: Your custom layer probably needs 3 arguments to be initialized, but doesn't receive them. You may have to add a `get_config()` method to it. This [issue's answer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1927#issuecomment-309712640) may help you, as well as the code for the core layers e.g. [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L214).

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness I am adding just a bit on top of the answer of benjaminplanche. If your custom layer `AttentionLayer` have any initial parameter that configure its behaviour you need to implement the `get_config` method of the class. Otherwise it will fail to load. I am writing this because I had a lot of troubles on how to load custom layers with arguments, so I'll leave it here.

For example, a dummy implementation of your layer:

```
class AttentionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        return super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        # Implementation about how to look with attention!
        return x

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

This will load with any of the approaches detailed in benjaminplanche's answer, i.e. using the `custom_objects={'AttentionLayer': AttentionLayer}`. However if your layer have some arguments the loading would fail.

Imagine the init method of your class have 2 paramters:

```
class AttentionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, **kwargs):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Then, when you load it with:

```
model = load_model('my_model.h5', custom_objects={'AttentionLayer': AttentionLayer})
```

It would throw this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file/cstm_layer.py", line 62, in <module>
    h = AttentionLayer()(x)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'param1' and 'param2'
```

In order to solve it you need to implement the `get_config` method in your custom layer class. An example:

```
class AttentionLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, **kwargs):
        self.param1 = param1
        self.param2 = param2
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    # ...

    def get_config(self):
        # For serialization with 'custom_objects'
        config = super().get_config()
        config['param1'] = self.param1
        config['param2'] = self.param2
        return config
```

So when you save the model, the saving routine will call the get_config and will serialize the inner state of your custom layer, i.e., the `self.params`. And when you load it, the loader will know how to initialize the inner state of your custom layer.

Comment: what are idx_init and idx_end please

Comment: Fixed, it is param1 and 2. In the get_config method you should store any Layer attributes relevant for its operation (in order to load the layer later with the correct conf)