# Keras ValueError: Unknown layer:name, when trying to load model to another platform

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, nvidia-jetson

I have trained a convolutional neural network using Keras 2.2.4 on Nvidia Quadro board. I have saved the trained model in tow separate files: one file (model.json) that describes the architecture and another file (model.h5) that has all the weights.

I want to load the saved model on the Nvidia Jetson TX2 board that runs Keras 2.2.2 and I'm trying to do it as follows:

```
# load json and create model
    json_file = open(prefix+'final_model.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
    loaded_model.load_weights(prefix+"model.h5")
    model = loaded_model
```

However, when I tried to load I got the following error:

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 368, in model_from_json
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/**init**.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 292, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/**init**.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 165, in deserialize_keras_object
    ':' + function_name)
**ValueError: Unknown layer:name**

I've also tried to save the whole model in one file, but got the same error.

I have tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837728/valueerror-unknown-layer-capsulelayer) but wasn't able to solve it.

Has anyone seen this error before? Any suggestions?

Comment: please ref to this solution too: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11617#issuecomment-509486741

it worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem yesterday, I just updated keras through conda and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I updated Keras to 2.2.4 on my Jetson board and worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be different `tensorflow` versions for me. The model was created with `tensorflow v2.1.0` and I was trying to load it with `tensorflow v1.10.0`. Just make sure that **tensorflow versions are consistent**.

Answer (score 0):

just update the keras package to recent one using following command

`conda update keras`