# ValueError: Unknown layer: Addons>InstanceNormalization

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, normalization, tensorflow-addons

I tried to load my weight into my model, but i got the following the error.

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: Addons>InstanceNormalization
```

I have already search for similar problems, the error they got as follow.

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: InstanceNormalization
```

[ValueError: Unknown layer: CapsuleLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837728/valueerror-unknown-layer-capsulelayer/50838031#50838031)

[ValueError: Unknown layer: Custom>CTCLayer. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960574/valueerror-unknown-layer-customctclayer-please-ensure-this-object-is-passed)

Most of the answers told them to add the custom layer you used in custom_objects in keras.models.load_model(), such as

```
keras.models.load_model(weight_path, custom_objects={'InstanceNormalization': InstanceNormalization})
```

However, that does not solve my problem. Another method i tried also not solve it.

```
with CustomObjectScope({'InstanceNormalization': InstanceNormalization}):
    gan_model = load_model(gan_model_path)
```

I am using tensorflow 2.0, tensorflow-addons 0.6.0 and keras 2.3.1 .